# Error when installing angular-cli on AWS EC2

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, angular-cli

Trying to install angular cli by running command below:

**npm install -g @angular/cli**

But getting an error that it cannot find module /postinstall/script.js

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Full error below:

```
/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.9.0/bin/ng -> /root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.9.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng

> @angular/cli@8.1.2 postinstall /root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.9.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

module.js:478
    throw err;
    ^

Error: Cannot find module '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v9.9.0/lib/node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/postinstall/script.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:476:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:424:25)
    at Module.runMain (module.js:611:10)
    at run (bootstrap_node.js:394:7)
    at startup (bootstrap_node.js:160:9)
    at bootstrap_node.js:507:3
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @angular/cli@8.1.2 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@8.1.2 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

Comment: Problem seems to come from you node installation. Could you add `node -v` command result to your question ?

Answer (score 0):

You seems to use node **v9.9.0** but since the last angular version, they encourage you to use nodejs **v12** or later (https://alligator.io/angular/angular-8/)

Try to upgrade your node version.